# paste date string in Sqlquery

Tags: sql, r, lubridate

Hi I have a date string that I want to paste in a sql query.

```
end_date <- today()
end_date <- as.character(end_date)


trs <- sqlQuery(con, sprintf(
               "select pts.PARTIJA,  pts.DATA, pts.OPIS, pts.IZNOS, pts.alfa4
                from pts
                where OPIS = 'something' and DATA > %s", end_date))
```

The error i'm getting is:

```
22018 245 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2012.01.31 ' to data type int.
```

Any idea how I can put the date in the query correctly?

Comment: I know. I also tried end_date <- "'"
end_date <- paste0(a, end_date, a)

Comment: The error message has `.` as separators rather than `-`. What does your `end_date` look like? Maybe your locale settings use `.` instead of `-` for date separators?

Comment: print(end_date) returns: "'2018-01-05'"

Comment: *Don't* try to parse the date, use the proper type for the field and *parameter* in a *parameterized query*. In any case, the unambiguous date format is the unseparated `YYYYMMDD`, not `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: Pasting a string into a SQL query is something you should NEVER do. This makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks which is one of the most common way hackers gain access to databases. Instead you should use parameters

Comment: By using string replacement in this case you expose yourself and your users to SQL injection attacks *and* conversion errors. Just don't do it this way. Don't use `sprintf`, concatenation or any other such trick to generate a SQL string. The query you built in this case is `AND DATA > 2018-01-05`. In other words `2002`, an integer

Comment: @Gregor *dates* have no format, they are binary values. The OP actually *formatted* a date as a string resulting in an invalid query. Instead of doing that, the date should be passed as a parameter to the query

Comment: @Prometheus you shouldn't use RODBC to connect to databases because it doesn't allow you to pass parameters. As you just found out, passing data as strings can result in quite a few problems. Wait until you try to pass Unicode data like German, French, Latvian text or ... emojis. Probably ones typed by users into a comment field you want to use for sentiment analysis. RODBCext allows you to pass parameters without converting them to strings. Check [Parameterized SQL queries](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBCext/vignettes/Parameterized_SQL_queries.html)

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll further research the topic.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I understand your rationale, but keep in mind that there *are* R users using dbs where sql injection is *literally* not a concern. It’s fine to recommend best practices, but try to be open to the fact that your advice might actually not apply to everyone.

Comment: Actually, this is such a case @joran. I'm working in a closed system. Regardless, its a good point to know. The only issue is, I'm still not sure why the query is not going through.

Comment: @joran except, the OP just stumbled on the conversion issues. This is very much a concern for R users too. Maybe not *American* users, but even UK users use different date and decimal formats so they should *avoid* converting data to strings

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos in one of the conditions i'm using cyrlic text. Could this be the issue?

Comment: @Prometheus this will probably be the *next* bug. The *current* one is that the way you formatted the string, you ended up with `DATA > 2018-01-06` which compares a field with the number that results from an arithmetic operation. Using parameterized queries would avoid both bugs. In this case you could have used quotes around the date to create `DATA > '2018-01-06`. That format is still locale specific though and could fail in some countries. The unambiguous date literal is `YYYYMMDD`, eg `DATA > '20180106'`

Comment: @Prometheus as for Cyrillic, if you *don't* use parameterized queries you have to prepend the values with `N`. Otherwise they are considered to be ASCII, eg ` NAME = N'Το όνομα μου'`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It seems we are in agreement then. Parameterized queries are advisable and in many circumstances necessary, but also not strictly necessary for some (even many) users in other situations.

Comment: @joran no, the opposite. They should be used in almost all cases if you need to pass data at runtime. There are some exceptions, eg: you don't need them for hard-coded literals eg `WHERE InUse = 1 and Date >'20000101'` or you are writing ad-hoc queries. If anything, its *easier* to use parameters than try to get the dynamic string properly quoted and escaped: `query <- "UPDATE cakes SET price = ? WHERE cake = ?";;
sqlExecute(connHandle, query, newData)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I guess we'll have to just disagree on this one, then.